# How to finish the Activity from inside the surface view?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make a game using surface view.  Its going good. I am getting help from here  http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html
I have a actvity that contentView is surface view object. What I want to do is to On Wining the game , If you ser touch the game , I want ot finish the activity and start a new acitvity of high score.

What I am doing is onTouch after win

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent ( getContext ( ) , HighScore.class );
                                    getContext ( ).startActivity ( intent );
                                }
                            }, 3000);
```

**Its start a new activity, but how can I finish the activity that hold the surface view? Because when I Press back from my High score activity the surface view holder activity displayed as It was not finished.**

Comment: you can do the same of this thread, i hope it be usefull

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679108/android-finishing-activity-from-class-view-by-touchevent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a reference to the activity toy want to finish. For example you can pass the activity to the surface view and call `finish()` method of the passed activity. Or you can post messages to an activity's handler, not view's.

Comment: Thanks now I understand the benefit of Handler.