# Android finishing activity from class view by touchEvent

Tags: android, view, android-activity, touch

I have got class GameActivity and in there a method `setContentView(GameView)`. In class `GameView` which extends `View` I have got a method:

```
public class GameView extends View{
...
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
         switch(event.getAction()){ 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:    
            Intent intent = new Intent (contexTmp, MainActivity.class); 
            contexTmp.startActivity(intent); 
            //finish(); //->how to finish this activity from class view 
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in class `GameView` in method `onTouchEvent()` when I pressed the button I am changing the activity to `MainActivity`. My problem is: how to finish the activity from class view (first I have to finished the present activity and after that go to next activity), because method: 
`finish()` doesn't work?

Comment: you must get a reference to activity and call finish method on them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) which returns the activity context used to create the view :

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) { 
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
          ...   
          ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your GameView is one of the views in the activity, you can simply call:

```
((Activity)getContext()).finish();
```

This will be the context of the activity that created the view. So just make sure that is the Activity you want to finish and you are good to go!